# Having a message box used as a variable in batch program

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe

I am attempting to have a batch program pop-up with yes or no options and depending what the user clicks will determine what the program will do.

for example:

```
@echo off

Echo x=msgbox^("Yes or No?",3,"Title"^)>"%temp%\msg.vbs"
start %temp%\msg.vbs

if %msgbox% == yes goto y
if %msgbox% == no goto n
if %msgbox% == cancel goto exit

y:
cls
echo You clicked yes.

n:
echo You clicked no.

exit:
cls
exit
```

Comment: `.vbs` (and `.js`) files are executed by a separate program `wscript.exe` aka [Windows Script Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host). Anything done in the script has no effect on your CMD.